# Keycloak REST API called with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin, keycloak, claims-based-identity

I need an easy and simple way to consume the Keycloak REST APIs from https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html with ASP.NET Core C#.

I tried using the https://github.com/mattmorg55/Owin.Security.Keycloak but where do I go from there? If I can, I prefer configuring the users, roles, etc without using this, but how much do I need to configure and develop? I just need a simple way to authenticate and call the APIs I need.

With this Keycloak extension I was able to get the User Claims, but nothing else. I think I am failing at the authorization part because Postman always gives back to me unauthorized access or the security Claims, that I do not understand too much, but it is the way this Owin.Keycloak extension is working.

The things I need:

1. Account Management via C# code (create user, modify password, change roles, etc)
2. Get all roles from the realm/client
3. Do everything in C# back-end

Comment: Anything with "OWIN" in the name is going to be middleware. This package is mostly likely for using this an authentication provider, not for generic access to the API. You need to find an actual client for this or create your own.

Comment: Hey @gemada, Any luck with your post? Even I am trying/looking for similar solution but with latest version of KC10.0.1. Please share me something if you have?